# Django template multiple url return

Tags: python, django, templates

I've 2 urls pointing to the same place:

```
url(r'^index/$', 'proj.views.index'),
url(r'^index/show_closed/$', 'proj.views.index'),
```

If I use in a template file this:

```
{% url proj.views.index %}
```

it' ll return `/index/show_closed`

and this is OK, but how can i make `{% url %}` to return only `/index` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [named patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns); giving your pattern a unique name:

```
url(r'^index/$', 'proj.views.index', name='index_direct'),
url(r'^index/show_closed/$', 'proj.views.index', name='index_closed'),
```

then refer to those names in the `{% url %}` tag instead of the view:

```
{% url 'index_direct' %}
{% url 'index_closed' %}
```